# Scheduled Apex Job Delay for Chained Jobs

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, asyncapexjob

I've ready several articles mentioning that in Spring '15 there will be a 5 minute delay added for chained Scheduled jobs.

This page https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/FlexQueue implies that it is linked to the Apex Flex Queue. It's not clear if this is part of the Apex Flex Queue critical update or if this will be a separate update, and when it will be put in place.

Does anyone know when this will be released as an update or if it is part of the Apex Flex Queue update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new org after spring 15 date, it will be automatically enabled. But if it is an existing org, you can enable it from critical update or leave it without updating. Please find more details in below link,
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_apex_flex_queue_ga.htm

Comment: Yes I understand the Apex Flex Queue. What I'd like to know is whether the scheduled delay for chained jobs is in the same critical update, or a separate one.